# the name 'windows' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use **windows.location** to redirect to another page in my web application,but it shows me the above mentioned error,so which files should be added to the page to use the same?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Adeel,i am unable to use that also....i have already tried the same....window/windows both shows the error.......

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: I am just making redirect to another page on click event of the link...since now, i have used response.redirect,but it sometimes doesnt working in ie 7 or less..so i wanted to use windows.location,but why it shows the error..its only a one line code windows.location('~/Default.aspx');

Comment: Where did you try this line? Codebehind or html/javascript? Note that you can't use the `~` from html/javascript, that needs to be resolved by server-side code.

Comment: In asp.net, you can use `Response.Redirect('http://your_url')` to redirect.

Comment: the javascript line `window.location` is a property, not a method. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is no window.location in asp.net. Instead try with bool value true in response.redirect as
Response.Redirect("default.aspx",True);